# What hotkeys are supported when reading a man page?

Tags: man, less

People usually know after running `man fdisk` that they can search with:

```
/foo
```

(where `foo` is the string to be searched for). They can also use <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDown</kbd> to scroll up and down. What other hotkeys are supported by `man`? Is there a list of them?

Answer (score 3):

Press "h" inside a man page for a list of commands you can use.

Answer (score 3):

It's not related to man, it's depends on your pager. You can set your pager like following:

`alias man="man -P most"`

Now your manual pages will be show with `most` command as a pager. Now you have to use `most` command options.

If you are using `less` pager, following keys are useful:

```
  g  <  ESC-<       *  Go to first line in file (or line N).
  G  >  ESC->       *  Go to last line in file (or line N).
  F                    Forward forever; like "tail -f".
  h  H                 Display this help.
  F                    Forward forever; like "tail -f".
  /pattern          *  Search forward for (N-th) matching line.
  ?pattern          *  Search backward for (N-th) matching line.
  n                *  Repeat previous search (for N-th occurrence).
  N                *  Repeat previous search in reverse direction.
  &pattern          *  Display only matching lines
  g  <  ESC-<       *  Go to first line in file (or line N).
  G  >  ESC->       *  Go to last line in file (or line N
```

If you are using `most` pager, following keys are useful:

```
  SPACE, D              *Scroll down one Screen.
  U, DELETE             *Scroll Up one screen.
  RETURN, DOWN          *Move Down one line.
  UP                    *Move Up one line.
  T                      Goto Top of File.
  B                      Goto Bottom of file.
  S, f, /               *Search forward
  ?                     *Search Backward
  N                     *Find next in current search direction
```

**NOTE:** You can read the `man` page or `--help` option of you arbitrary pager or pressing `h` for help while using pager.

Comment: Apparently `most` is not installed by default in every linux (Mint/Ubuntu), `less` seems more prevalent, it's description includes "As part of the GNU project,
it is widely regarded as the standard pager on UNIX-derived systems."

Comment: @Xen2050, Exactly! I installed it with `yum`.